# a stuff/convert on getDate returns null?

Tags: t-sql, datetime, type-conversion

I'm concatinating a string in TSQL to a log. And sometimes the value below becomes `'NULL'`:

```
ISNULL(STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),GETDATE(), 127), 20, 4,''), 'NULL')
```

I figure it can depend on different user settings when executing? Because GetDate() would never return null, neither would the convert? So how is this possible?

Comment: We really need a [mre] here. I suspect there is *something else* going on here.

Comment: On a different note, that `STUFF` is actually some what pointless. Just `CONVERT` the value to a `varchar(19)` to truncate the milliseconds.

Comment: @ThomA, Yeah I understand the information is very vague. But when I notice the query has returned null in my log, I can rerun the query to notice that this time it doesn't. So I can't give any examples :/